# Ruby on rails: большое условие в контроллере

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с незнакомой мне ситуацией, в разработке новичок, нуждаюсь в совете.

Имеется контроллер с экшеном 'update'

```
def update
    @arrival = find_arrival
    @details = @arrival.arrival_details

    if check_conditions(@arrival)
      flash[:notice] = 'Документ прихода отредактирован'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Возникла ошибка. Проверьте правильность заполнения формы'
    end
    redirect_to edit_admin_arrival_path(@arrival)
  end
```

а так же следующие private-методы:

```
def check_conditions(arrival)
  new_status = arrival_params[:status]

  case @arrival.status
  when 'draft'
    return unless check_dependencies
    recalculate_balance if new_status == 'accrued'
    @arrival.update(arrival_params)
  when 'canceled'
    return unless new_status == 'draft'
    @arrival.update(status: arrival_params[:status])
  when 'accrued'
    return if new_status == 'draft'
    recalculate_balance if new_status == 'canceled'
    @arrival.update(new_status)
  end
end

def recalculate_balance
  puts '[PRY] recalculated'
end

def check_dependencies
  Provider.exists?(arrival_params[:provider_id]) &&
  Warehouse.exists?(arrival_params[:warehouse_id])
end
```

Интересует следующее - стоит ли выносить данное условие в отдельный класс или какой-нибудь там Service Object? Не думаю, что такому огромному условию место в контроллере. Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам `update` вполне себе нормальный.

Разве что выкинул бы оттуда `@details`, т. к. он всё равно доступен в `@arrival`. Но это мелочь. Если так удобно, пользуйтесь.
Ещё я бы переименовал ассоциацию `:arrival_details` в просто `:details`, чтобы снизить избыточность и необходимость в `@details`.

Но секция `private` перегружена, да. У вас туда утекла бизнес-логика. А контроллер не должен содержать бизнес-логики вообще, по-хорошему. Он должен лишь предоставлять к ней доступ.

Куда вы это вынесете, зависит от кучи факторов. В разных условиях решениями могут быть:

- В модель `Arrival` (по `@arrival`, так же она называется?)
- В Service Object

  - если модель и так слишком толстая
  - если действие затрагивает и другие модели тоже
- В модель с обобщением части логики наружу для повторного использования

  - если используемая в модели логика может быть хорошо обобщена
- ...?

Скажем, что вижу в вашем конкретном случае я:

- В `check_conditions` у вас вышла самодельная [*машина состояний*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82). Это достаточно популярная штука, у неё есть реализации вроде [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm), позволяющие оформить код компактнее и читаемее.
- `check_conditions` не только проверяет условия, но и обновление выполняет. И вообще он настолько часто ссылается на `@arrival`, что возникает здравый вопрос: а не должно ли это быть его методом?

  - [Статический анализатор Reek](https://github.com/troessner/reek) выполняет анализ "не ссылается ли метод на что-то больше, чем на `self`" и выводит предупреждение, если что-то подходит. Но не относитесь к Reek слишком серьёзно, думайте своей головой в первую очередь.
- `check_dependencies` должен скорее быть **в модели**, чем-то вроде:

  ```
  validates :provider, :warehouse, presence: true
  ```

  Да, тупо валидацией! Но стоит её дополнительно подкрепить **внешним ключом** с `NOT NULL` на уровне БД, чтобы никакие баги в приложении не могли привести к существованию `Arrival` с несуществующими `provider_id` и `warehouse_id`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробный и объемный ответ